# Oracle SQL: Further sort PARTITION BY groups based on first row in each partition

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, partition-by

I currently have a very large query, and am trying to further sort the data in a specific way. The query returns data in the following way, with items sorted by TimeToComplete descending:

```
|   id     |    ItemKey     |TimeToComplete|
| -------- | -------------- |--------------|
| ABC      | KEY-211-01     |    580       |
| DEF      | KEY-311-01     |    456       |
| GHI      | KEY-111-01     |    150       |
| JKL      | KEY-411-01     |     87       |
| XYZ      | KEY-311-01     |     23       |
| KNE      | KEY-211-01     |     17       |
```

What I am trying to do is sort this data so like ItemKeys are grouped together, but otherwise still retains the TimeToComplete sorting based on the first item in the group. Example like so:

```
|   id     |    ItemKey     |TimeToComplete|
| -------- | -------------- |--------------|
| ABC      | KEY-211-01     |    580       |
| KNE      | KEY-211-01     |     17       |
| DEF      | KEY-311-01     |    456       |
| XYZ      | KEY-311-01     |     23       |
| GHI      | KEY-111-01     |    150       |
| JKL      | KEY-411-01     |     87       |
```

I do have a partially working example, but it has some issues:

```sql
WITH GroupedRecords AS (
  SELECT 
          OriginalQuery.*,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by ItemKey order by TimeToComplete DESC) as RN
  FROM (originally giant query here) OriginalQuery  
),
Sequence AS (
  SELECT 
         ItemKey,
         TimeToComplete,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by TimeToComplete DESC) as SequenceOrder
  FROM GroupedRecords
  WHERE RN = 1
)
select T.*, s.SequenceOrder
from GroupedRecords T
INNER JOIN Sequence S ON T.ItemKey = S.ItemKey
ORDER BY S.SequenceOrder ASC, T.TimeToComplete DESC
```

The problems with this are:

1. The inner join between GroupedRecords and the Sequence changes a bunch of my column names (but not all of them) to Oracle's randomly generated names (QCSJ_0000006)
2. The join is also makes the query way too slow (OriginalQuery is already not very optimized, but this is doubling its execution time)

Question:
Is there a more efficient way I can achieve this sorting without using the sequence/join parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, you only need to add an analytic `max()` to the `order by` clause. You don't need to do **anything else**.

Suppose "current query" is your existing query, not ordered yet in any way (no `order by` clause). Add the following at the very end:

```
... existing query ...
order  by max(timetocomplete) over (partition by itemkey) desc,
          itemkey,
          timetocomplete desc
;
```

Note that you do **not** need to add the analytic function to the `select` clause. The SQL standard says you do; Oracle syntax says you don't. Oracle is taking care of the small additional steps for us, behind the scenes.

This computes the max time to complete for each key. It orders by that max first. In the case of ties (two or more different keys with the same **max** time to complete), it further orders by **key** first, and then within each key, by time to complete (descending).

Comment: +1 
" it further orders by key first, and then within each key, by time to complete (descending)."

Thanks! This fully covers the scenario

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following window function to your select list and then order the results as follows:

```
SELECT id, ItemKey, TimeToComplete
     , MAX(TimeToComplete) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemKey) AS max_time
  FROM data
 ORDER BY max_time DESC, ItemKey, TimeToComplete DESC
;
```

Result:

```
+------+------------+----------------+----------+
| id   | ItemKey    | TimeToComplete | max_time |
+------+------------+----------------+----------+
| ABC  | KEY-211-01 |            580 |      580 |
| KNE  | KEY-211-01 |             17 |      580 |
| DEF  | KEY-311-01 |            456 |      456 |
| XYZ  | KEY-311-01 |             23 |      456 |
| GHI  | KEY-111-01 |            150 |      150 |
| JKL  | KEY-411-01 |             87 |       87 |
+------+------------+----------------+----------+
```

Result, with data to test when two `ItemKey`s have the same `max_time`:

```
+------+------------+----------------+----------+
| id   | ItemKey    | TimeToComplete | max_time |
+------+------------+----------------+----------+
| ABC  | KEY-211-01 |            580 |      580 |
| KNE  | KEY-211-01 |             17 |      580 |
| ABD  | KEY-211-02 |            580 |      580 |
| ABE  | KEY-211-02 |            200 |      580 |
| DEF  | KEY-311-01 |            456 |      456 |
| XYZ  | KEY-311-01 |             23 |      456 |
| GHI  | KEY-111-01 |            150 |      150 |
| JKL  | KEY-411-01 |             87 |       87 |
+------+------------+----------------+----------+
```

You can generate the same result without the extra column by using a CTE term to add the new column, order by that in the outer query expression, but don't select that column in the outer query expression select list.

As follows:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
        SELECT id, ItemKey, TimeToComplete
             , MAX(TimeToComplete) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemKey) AS max_time
          FROM data
     )
SELECT id, ItemKey, TimeToComplete
  FROM cte1
 ORDER BY max_time DESC, ItemKey, TimeToComplete DESC
;
```

Result (updated with extra data):

```
+------+------------+----------------+
| id   | ItemKey    | TimeToComplete |
+------+------------+----------------+
| ABC  | KEY-211-01 |            580 |
| KNE  | KEY-211-01 |             17 |
| ABD  | KEY-211-02 |            580 |
| ABE  | KEY-211-02 |            200 |
| DEF  | KEY-311-01 |            456 |
| XYZ  | KEY-311-01 |             23 |
| GHI  | KEY-111-01 |            150 |
| JKL  | KEY-411-01 |             87 |
+------+------------+----------------+
```

[Working test case - Updated to handle case raised by @mathguy](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8d81831f3f3f2358814d4ed55b0c2846)

Comment: This is not enough - it does not guarantee that, within a constant ItemKey, the rows are further ordered by TimeToComplete descending. (That can be added easily to your answer.)

Comment: @mathguy Yes.  It does: `ORDER BY max_time DESC, TimeToComplete DESC` ... That `max_time` is the same value for all the matching `ItemKey` values, then the secondary sort is done on the original `TimeToComplete DESC`.  See the Working test case.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer. What it does **not** do is to keep rows with the same ItemKey together, as the OP requested. That will come into play only when two ItemKeys (two distinct ones) have the same max_TimeToComplete. Again, this is easy to fix (just add to `order by`).

Comment: No, it doesn't - in the case I mentioned already. Suppose you have two different keys, KEY-AAA and KEY-BBB. They have values 300, 200, 100 and 300, 150 respectively. The first ordering expression doesn't distinguish between the keys (both have max = 300). The second expression orders by values: 300, 300, 200, 150, 100 - and now the keys are intermixed.

Comment: @mathguy  Yes.  I agree.  It's ok when `max_time` is distinct in the result over different `ItemKey` values.  That needs to be addressed. I'll add data to the test case for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235861/discussion-between-jon-armstrong-and-mathguy).

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! However now that you brought up the case with the same TimeToComplete on the same ItemKey, (and sorry if the question wasn't clear enough) each group of ItemKeys should be sorted by TimeToComplete Descending as well. So in your example, for KEY-211-01, the order should be 580, 580, 200, 17

Comment: @ChrisMonteiro Look closely.  It think I made those ItemKeys different on purpose.  One is KEY-211-01 and the other is KEY-211-02.  That's why they are separated.  All the rows for each are kept together, but each group has a max_time of 580, so we could decide to order them slightly differently, to break the tie.

Comment: @JonArmstrong Ah yes my bad! I see it working, thank you!